# Regular singular, Irregular singular & Ordinary points of an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions

I'm currently trying to re pick up physics after a few years off.. but I'm not sure on the current question and I have no idea what it actually means.

My mathematics is not great but it reminds me of poles from complex analysis stuff.

If some one could tell me the answer and more importantly the reason why I would be very grateful. even point me in the direction of further reading if you can. 
$$
x y'' -\frac2{x(x-2)}y'+x^2y  = 0
$$
which is true?

- $x=0$ is a regular singular point of this equation.
- $x=0$ is an irregular singular point of this equation.
- $x=0$ is an ordinary point of this equation.
- $x=2$ is an irregular singular point of this equation.

Comment: If you have no idea what something means, then a good start would be to put each of the weird words into google. I tried to make your post use Mathjax but it seems that you have reverted the change; please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and do it yourself so that it is easier to read. Also your post will likely be closed if you don't show some effort

Comment: I am showing effort dude, Ive found the definitions on google, however Its the wording which confufes me ]

Comment: Im currently trying to pick up physics again after several years off so I am very rusty

Comment: Your background is important information that should also go in the post. I don't see any effort that allows someone to begin to help you from. You should make your question about the definitions more specific; as it stands, you're asking someone to write a small section of a textbook. Why not go read a textbook then?

Comment: A quick defintion would suffice

Comment: but you said that you have already seen them by google, so how does that help? For instance http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSingularPoint.html ?

Comment: Thanks ill take a look.. My problem is the wording of a lot of methematical texta I struggle with being dyslex.

Comment: Another thing, at the bottom of that page (and many pages) is a "References" section, that's usually a good place to look for more information. In this case you might want to consult Arfken, G. "Singular Points." §8.4 in Mathematical Methods for Physicists, 3rd ed. Orlando, FL: Academic Press, pp. 451-453 and 461-463, 1985.

Comment: Thanks for that Calvin

Answer (score 0):

Singular: You can not compute the general highest derivative of the equation at this point due to division-by-zero. Here that is the second derivative. Obviously, $x=0$ and $x=2$ are singular.

Regular singularity: You can, after applying some factor, write the equation as
$$
(x-c)^2y''(x)+(x-c)p(x)y'(x)+q(x)y(x)=0
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are continuous in $x=c$. It does not play any role if these functions have additional roots in $x=c$. What makes this situation "regular" is that the equation is essentially an Euler-Cauchy equation 
$$
(x-c)^2y''(x)+(x-c)p(c)y'(x)+q(c)y(x)=0
$$
with some perturbation terms added. And it is known how solve Euler-Cauchy equations, as they are equivalent to linear equations with constant coefficients.

---

- $x=0$:
  $$ x^2y''(x)-\frac{2}{x-2}y'(x)+x^3y(x)=0 $$
  fails this test in the middle term, thus a irregular singularity.
- $x=2$:
  $$ (x-2)^2y''(x)-(x-2)\frac2xy'(x)+x^2(x-2)^2y(x)=0$$ fits the pattern, thus a regular singularity.